# Excel: Multiply each cell in row X by corresponding cell in row 2, and get sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table set up as follows:

```
Column 1 - Customer Name
Row 1 - Item Name
Row 2 - Item Cost
Row 3+- Item Quantity
```

How do I set up the last column to calculate the total cost for each customer? I.e, For each customer row, I want to multiply the number in each cell (= quantity) by the corresponding cell in Row 2 (= cost), and add them all up for the final bill.

To clarify what I'm saying I'm attaching the following picture so that we can discuss specifics.
[image]

Comment: I've been doing =(A71*$A$2)+(B71*$B$2)+(C71*$C$2).....  It works, but but there must be a better way.. It needs to be manually updated every time I add a new column/item, and gets messed up every time I delete a column..

Comment: Try removing `$`-s (designation of absolutely addressed rows or columns)

Comment: That won't help - If I do that and drag the formula down to all rows, it just multiplies each row by the row above it- I need "Row 2" to be "absolutely addressed", since that's where the costs are.

Comment: It's REALLY hard to propose without seeing data.

Comment: @user2545345 I added a picture with a simple table to give you an idea of what I understood. Feel free to upload another if this is not what you had in mind. As David Jashi said, it's hard to help you without a visual and specifics.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried `SUMPRODUCT` - it does exactly what you need, gives the sum of 2 or more multiplied ranges?

`=SUMPRODUCT(A71:C71,$A$2:$C$2)`

You can extend the ranges as far as you need. If you want to add columns make sure you don't add at the end, e.g. if you retain one blank column (D currently) and include that in the formula, then if you add a column at D the formula will automatically extend to E

Answer (score 0):

You can use sumproduct but specify the ranges, e.g. `=sumproduct(B2:B6,C2:C6)`, the next row would then be `=sumproduct(B2:B6,D2:D6)` etc.  I'm sure there's a way to "fix" your cost row but it's quite quick doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your first data set is in column A (i.e. per unit cost) and the second data set is in column B (i.e. quantity), and you want the total cost for each item for the specified quantity, place the following formula in C1

=A1*B1

Select C1 and drag the fill handle - this is the small
black square at the bottom right corner of the cursor as far down the column as you need. The program will automatically replicate the formula with the correct cell numbers for each row.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use this formula:

`=SUM(B4:B5)*B2+SUM(C4:C5)*C2`

It is not so cool but you still need to expand the formula even with `SUMPRODUCT` because the range has to be the same as far as I know.

The other way I came up will use a matrix function called `MMULT` and here is the example:

[image]

With this array (means you have to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> altogether) formula entered into `cell D6`: `=SUM(MMULT(B2:C2,TRANSPOSE(B3:C5)))`, you will get your expected result without needing all the subtotals.  Please note this is a `2 x 1 By 2 x 3` `Matrix`formula.